# Code for testing of data in a neural network after the training is complete

Tags: python, numpy, testing, neural-network, training-data

I have modified a code found online for my use. The training of neural network is complete. But I am not sure how to go about with the testing of the data-set. My data-set consists of 350 entries, of which half I want to use for training and the other half for testing. Can anyone help me with how the code will look like in the testing module? 
The structure of neural network :
It has 3 hidden layers
It has 34 columns
Thank you

This is my working code used in training:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

X = X = np.array([[float(cell) for cell in row[:-1]] for row in      csv.reader(open('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/final sem/Project/Implementation/nn.csv'))])

Y = np.array([float(row[-1]) for row in   csv.reader(open('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/final sem/Project/Implementation/nn.csv'))])

syn0 = 2*np.random.random((34,26)) - 1

syn1 = 2*np.random.random((26,18)) - 1

syn2 = 2*np.random.random((18,11)) - 1


syn3 = 2*np.random.random((11,6)) - 1


for j in xrange(350):

  l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
  l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l1.dot(syn1))))
  l3 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l2.dot(syn2))))
  l4 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l3.dot(syn3))))

  l4_delta = (Y[j] - l4)*(l4*(1-l4))
  l3_delta = l4_delta.dot(syn3.T) * (l3 * (1-l3))
  l2_delta = l3_delta.dot(syn2.T) * (l2 * (1-l2))
  l1_delta = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T) * (l1 * (1-l1))

  syn3 += np.dot(l3.transpose(),l4_delta)
  syn2 += np.dot(l2.transpose(),l3_delta)
  syn1 += np.dot(l1.transpose(),l2_delta)
  syn0 += X.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

Comment: Sorry, no smart answer, but usually it's 1/3 of data for testing and 2/3 for learning.

Comment: okay i will do that.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood it, you want to use a neural network for **classification of your data-set's entries**.
So after training, your network might be able to group those entries in **6 different classes**, since your last layer has 6 *neurons*.

Here's what I would to:

- Take one of the entries of the data-set
- Use the entry to calculate the network's output, i.e., use the same update of the `for` loop up until the line `l4 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l3.dot(syn3))))`. (After training, you do not update the synaptic weights `syn0,syn1, ...` anymore).
- You will get an output of 6 values in `l4`, that you have to interprete.
- I think the usual interpretation goes like this: let's say the **3rd value** in `l4` **is largest**, then your sample is of **category 3**.
- Now, most samples that are similar to the previous one, should be classified as an category 3 item as well.
- This way, your neural network should be able to recognize patterns in your samples

I hope this is somewhat helpful. This is very generalized, but so is your example, since we do not know what your data is, what it looks like, or what you are searching for in it.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply. The database is a dermatology data-set. And there are 6 types of skin diseases which is to be predicted.  So my query is that is the testing performed below the training code? and are the weighs saved and used for the testing part?

Comment: Okay i think i got it.. So basically the weights after the loop is completed in the training code are saved in some array which are later used in the testing code. The new testing code contains the same code as the training except the loop goes on till `l4 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l3.dot(syn3))))` and the weights are initialised at the start by the values obtained during the training. Is this right ?

Comment: Okay, now I get your question better. Sorry for not including this before: You should split training and testing. Run your training for loop for the fraction of your data you want to use for testing. (If training takes some time, e.g. for bigger data sets, I'd suggest saving the `syn` arrays, and loading them for testing/classification, so you don't have to repeat same training all the time.) Then, run a second loop for classification of the remaining data.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's how I would do it.

Comment: Okay so the second loop will just use a new **X** input which is from the testing data-set and no changes to the weights.. Thank you so much ..  :)

Comment: so i tried the testing of data .. But the output doesn't seem correct. Few are correct.. but for some the highest value does not state which class it is.. (The correct one). For how long should the iteration go on for accurate results?

Comment: `X = X = np.array([[float(cell) for cell in row[:-1]] for row in csv.reader(open('C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/final sem/Project/Implementation/nnpart2.csv'))])
for k in xrange(50):
    l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
    l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l1.dot(syn1))))
    l3 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l2.dot(syn2))))
    l4 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(l3.dot(syn3))))

print l4`                                                                                                                   I have appended this code after the testing

Comment: I think it really depends on your data how much training it needs. I don't have so much experience, all my knowledge is quite theoretical, so I can't tell you any concrete numbers. A set of 350 data sounds like a low number to me. Is the data easily classifiable by humans, or is that a hard task for humans as well? Might be that it's really hard to recognize patterns in your data.

Comment: okay so according to you the code is fine ?its just the data-set which is giving the minor errors in predicting..

Comment: I think so. The code looks fine to me. I didn't check it too much, you said you got it from some working example? And it gives you output of the desired dimension/structure or whatever to call it, so I think it's fine